# How to change the hostname in Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Tags: hostname

```
sudo nano /etc/hostname
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

With above I couldn't change the name, because there is an error showing :

```
read only permission
```

at the bottom of the window

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudoedit` (see `man sudoedit`) to edit those files as,

```
sudoedit /etc/hostname
sudoedit /etc/hosts
```

They're protected against casual modification.

Comment: It's nice support it workout..thanks..but after reboot hostname was same as old..It did not change permanently. Pls let me know how to change the hostname permanently. ..thanks again..

Comment: I'm working on kernel GNU/Linux 4.4.0-47-generic 1606